# Matrix with positive diagonal elements

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I was wondering if a symmetric matrix with positive elements only in the diagonal (negative elsewhere) is any special beside the symmetry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user5503 stackoverflow : `A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers`. What's your programming language?